# Compiling C# to JavaScript using Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c#, emscripten

The [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) github page states that "it takes LLVM bitcode - which can be generated from C/C++, using llvm-gcc (DragonEgg) or clang, or any other language that can be converted into LLVM - and compiles that into JavaScript."

A goal of the [LLILC](http://blog.llvm.org/2015/04/llilc-llvm-based-compiler-for-dotnet.html) project is a "Just in Time (JIT) compiler for CoreCLR" based on LLVM.

How can I combine Emscripten with LLILC (or any other C#-to-LLVM compiler) to compile C# to JavaScript?

I've seen many references to this possibility since the emscripten project was created, but no clear explanations. This isn't the kind of thing one figures out in an hour or two, hence this question.

Answer (score 1):

LLILC is still in very early development. You can instead use [JSIL](http://jsil.org/) to use a fairly large part of C# in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Which features of C# are you trying to use that JSIl doesn't support?

Comment: The original question is about using Emscripten, not JSIL. You suggest that it is possible to compile through Emscripten via JSIL, So am just asking how, as I can't find any information on doing this. JSIL by itself is not an answer to the original question.

Comment: I understand that your question is about using Emscripten, but on its own Emscripten can't do that. You mention LLILC, but it's too early to use reliably.